# How do you compare array objects to summarize values?

Tags: vba, excel

In this macro I am comparing all of our company's customer accounts that have been affected on a specific date (previous day) to all of our reported payments from our bank statement. I use a VLookup to compare each customer amount in the bank statement column and visa-versa with bank records to customer accounts.

I take the ones that are unapplied (those that report an error in the VLookup - ErrorHandler: and ErrorHandler2:) and modify a dynamic Array to store their values (GPMissing1() for Customer Name and GPMissing2() for Customer Amounts)

```
Sub GPWireDifference()
    Dim GPMissing1() As String, GPMissing2() As Double, GPCount As Integer

    GPMissingString = ""
    Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Range("B:E").NumberFormat = "$#,##0.00"
    Range("D2").Activate

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler:
    Do Until ActiveCell.Offset(0, -3).Value = ""
        ActiveCell.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction. _
            IfError(Application.WorksheetFunction. _
                VLookup(ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2), Range("C:C"), 1, False), 0)


        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
        If ActiveCell.Row = 300 Then
            Exit Sub
        End If

    Loop
    ErrorHandler:
        If Not ActiveCell.Offset(0, -3).Value = "" Then
            GoTo ErrorHandler2:
        End If
    ErrorHandler2:
        If Not ActiveCell.Offset(0, -3).Value = "" Then
            ReDim Preserve GPMissing1(GPCount)
            ReDim Preserve GPMissing2(GPCount)
            GPMissing1(GPCount) = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -3).Value
            GPMissing2(GPCount) = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2).Value
            GPCount = GPCount + 1
            Resume Next
        End If

    For x = 0 To GPCount - 1
        If x > 0 Then
            GPMissingString = GPMissingString & vbCr & GPMissing1(x) & " - " & GPMissing2(x)
        Else
            GPMissingString = GPMissing1(x) & " - " & GPMissing2(x)
        End If
    Next
    Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    If GPCount > 0 Then MsgBox GPMissingString

End Sub
```

In the end, it displays a MsgBox to alert the user of all accounts that have been affected but are not reflected in the bank statement.

Example Message:

```
In Great Plains But Not In Bank Statement:
    Rod Powers - $196.40           'Array Object 0 - Array Object 0
    Rod Powers - $394.40           'Array Object 1 - Array Object 1
    Tod Dindino - $1,190.40        'Array Object 2 - Array Object 2
    Rod Powers - $2,752.80         'Array Object 3 - Array Object 3
    Tod Dindino - $12,518.75       'Array Object 4 - Array Object 4
```

Since these are two separate arrays, yet each array position matches its respective value in the other array, how would I be able to summarize each message to show:

```
In Great Plains But Not In Bank Statement:
    Rod Powers - $3,343.60          
    Tod Dindino - $13,709.15
```

(We received bank wires for customer orders and sometimes the customer sends a single wire to reflect multiple orders. This summation would allow me to then further compare a wire for the summation of single customer names rather than line by line values. I.e. I can compare the total of Rod Powers to his single wire, versus his 3 individual orders vs his wire which obviously returns as a missing value)

Here's an example of what the sheet will look like:
[image]

SOLUTION/FIXED:

As per Mat's Mug's help, I have eliminated the use of a dynamic array and switched it to a Dictionary. This allowed me to create a total sum of all repeated names and further compare to any values on the bank statement.

```
Sub GPWireDifference()

    Dim values As Dictionary
    Set values = New Dictionary

    Dim lookup As String
    Dim amount As Currency
    lastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    GPMissingString = ""

    Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Range("B:E").NumberFormat = "$#,##0.00"
    Range("D2").Activate

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler:
    Do Until ActiveCell.Offset(0, -3).Value = ""
        ActiveCell.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction. _
            IfError(Application.WorksheetFunction. _
                VLookup(ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2), Range("C:C"), 1, False), 0)
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
    Loop

    ErrorHandler:
        If Not ActiveCell.Offset(0, -3).Value = "" Then
            GoTo ErrorHandler2:
        End If

    ErrorHandler2:
        If Not ActiveCell.Offset(0, -3).Value = "" Then
            lookup = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -3).Value
            amount = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2).Value
            If values.Exists(lookup) Then
                values(lookup) = values(lookup) + amount
            Else
                values.Add lookup, amount
            End If
            Resume Next
        End If

    For x = 0 To values.Count - 1
        If x > 0 Then
            GPMissingString = GPMissingString & vbCr & values.Keys(x) & " - " & _
                Format(values.Items(x), "$#,##0.00")values.Items(x)
        Else
            GPMissingString = values.Keys(x) & " - " & _
                Format(values.Items(x), "$#,##0.00")values.Items(x)
        End If
    Next
    Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    If values.Count > 0 Then MsgBox GPMissingString

End Sub
```

Thank you everyone! I'm blown away by how much and how quickly y'all have been able to help me through the years!

Comment: Look into `Collections` and `.Exists` to add the values when a match is found.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman I'm not very familiar with VBA, as I've only begun to research it about 4 days ago, but I do have an understanding of the sytax structure due to my previous experience with Java. With that said, would Collections be essentially establishing a dynamic array? Or do you have a data sheet to describe these? (I am at work, so some forums are unfortunately blocked)

Comment: see if [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f26wd2e5(v=vs.100).aspx) helps

Comment: @ScottHoltzman `Collection` doesn't expose an `Exists` member. Were you thinking of `Scripting.Dictionary.Exist`? ;-)

Comment: @ScottHoltzman So essentially instead of using a dynamic array, mostly to save repetitious coding, use a collection. I see in your referenced document, the author constantly refers to the Object's ToString method prior to modifying the collection. Would this inhibit storing values (Integer, Double, Long)? I understand the accessing, but how would i be able to compare repeated names and to combine the values? I.e. `For x = 0 To collName.Count` `collName(1) = collName(x) Then` `collNum(1) = collNum(1) + collNum(x)` `Next` Then remove all collNum(x)?

Comment: @Mat'sMug - Yes. Thank you! It's been a while since I worked with those. Munkeeface, ignore my comments, and stick with Mat'sMug on this one :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Array lookup is going to be ***O(n)***, which means the more items there are, the longer the lookup is going to be.

Make yourself a `Dictionary` object (reference the *Microsoft Scripting Runtime* library for early-binding) instead - a dictionary key lookup is ***O(1)***, which means lookup time remains constant regardless of how many items there are:

```
Dim values As Dictionary
Set values = New Dictionary

Dim lookup As String
Dim amount As Currency

For row = 2 To lastRow
     lookup = Sheet1.Range("A" & row).Value
     amount = Sheet1.Range("B" & row).Value
     If values.Exists(lookup) Then
         values(lookup) = values(lookup) + amount
     Else
         values.Add lookup, amount
     End If
Next
```

A `Collection` can also be keyed, but the keys cannot be retrieved or iterated, and its members are just too bare-bones; a `Dictionary` will do a much better job.

Comment: After researching Dictionary (vs Array/Collection), it seems this is exactly what I need... I will try to modify my code to utilize Dictionary instead of the arrays I've been using and will report back on my findings.

Comment: Ok it works fantastically! In my conversion to string bit (for the MsgBox), however, I am getting the values (items in Dictionary) returning as ##.# when there is a zero in the second decimal place. Is there a way to format this? I would like it to output `$###.00` with the .00 showing any following decimals. It is currency I am reporting on, after all

Comment: Try `Format(amount, "$#,##0.00")` - also, consider marking the answer as accepted if it fixed your problem. Cheers!

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much! I have modified the original post to reflect the solution, including your `Format` suggestion

Comment: People usually expect the question to contain the question, and the answers to contain the answer, but cool, good to hear =)

Answer (score 1):

The trivial way would be to search the name array to see if the name exists, and if it does then add the value to the existing value instead of inserting a new array member